# iterate component using *ngFor

Tags: angular

I am facing problem generating components using ngFor directive in angular2.

My desired component model tree is: 
    RootComponent
        ArticlesComponent
                Article_1
                Article_2
                Article_N

```
**RootComponent.html**
<section>Html for root component goes here</section>
<articles>This contains the articles html and will act as container for enumerated article tags</articles>

**Articles.component.ts**


 import {Component} from "@angular/core";
 import {ArticleComponent} from "./article.component";


 @Component({
             moduleId : module.id,
             selector : 'articles-list',
             template : `<div class="row">
                           <ul>
                             <li *ngFor="let article of articles" >
                                       <article [title]="article.title"
                                       [link]="article.link"></article>
                             </li>
                           </ul>
                        </div>`
           })


 export class ArticleListComponent{

     public articles :ArticleComponent[];

     constructor(){
        this.articles = [];
        let articleObj1 = new ArticleComponent("title1","link1");
        let articleObj2 = new ArticleComponent("title2","link2");
        this.articles.push(articleObj1);
        this.articles.push(articleObj2);
     }

  }

  **Article.component.ts**

   import {Component,Input} from "@angular/core";

   @Component({
               moduleId: module.id,
               selector: 'article',
               templateUrl: `<div class ="row">
                               <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                               <h5><a href="#" >{{link}}</a></h5> 
                             </div>`
             })


   export class ArticleComponent {

         @Input() title : string;
         @Input() link : string;

         public count:number;

         constructor(title,link){
                this.title = title;
                this.link = link;
         }

         incrementCount(){
            this.count++;
         }


     }
```

System.js throws an error :

```
(SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for ArticleComponent: (?, ?).↵  Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ArticleComponent: (?, ?).↵
```

What does this error actually mean and how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

`ArticleComponent` is instantiated by Angulars DI. If it has parameters, they need to be resolvable by DI. `title` and `link` are not resolvable, because there are no providers. Parameters without type annotations also would need an `@Injectable()` decorator.

I think the right approach is to remove the parameters from the constructor and instead use only the inputs.

```
 export class ArticleComponent {

     @Input() title : string;
     @Input() link : string;

     public count:number;

     /*constructor(title,link){
            this.title = title;
            this.link = link;
     }*/

     incrementCount(){
        this.count++;
     }
 }
```

also the constructor in `ArticleListComponent` can be shortened, because as mentioned DI creates the component instances.

```
 export class ArticleListComponent{

     public articles :ArticleComponent[];

     /*
     constructor(){
        this.articles = [];
        let articleObj1 = new ArticleComponent("title1","link1");
        let articleObj2 = new ArticleComponent("title2","link2");
        this.articles.push(articleObj1);
        this.articles.push(articleObj2);
     }*/
  }
```

all you need is the data for `*ngFor`, the rest is done by `<article>`

```
 export class ArticleListComponent{

     public articles :ArticleComponent[];

     constructor(){
        this.articles = [{title: "title1",link: "link1"}, {title: "title2",link: "link2"}];
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code , just change

```
let articleObj1 = {"title":"title1","link" : "link1"};
let articleObj2 = {"title":"title2","link" : "link2"};
```

And you will get , desired output.

There is no need to do :

```
let articleObj1 = new ArticleComponent("title1","link1");
let articleObj2 = new ArticleComponent("title2","link2");
```

Error is related to the `ArticleComponent("title1","link1")` , Your `ArticleComponent` doesn't have those two params in constructor.